# Create a dynamic date range based on specific day - Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: date, dynamic, oracle-sqldeveloper, truncate

I want to return values between the 16th of the last month to today, but need the 16th of the last month to be dynamic so I don't have to change the month everytime

This is what the code is now:

WHERE
date between '2023-01-16' and '2023-02-15'

I need it to be more like this:

WHERE
date between 'YYYY-MM-16' and now()

Answer (score 0):

This is one option to get 16th of previous month (today is 14th of March 2023):

```
SQL> select trunc(add_months(sysdate, -1), 'mm') + 15 start_value
  2  from dual;

START_VALU
----------
2023-02-16

SQL>
```

Therefore, your query would then have

```
where date_column between trunc(add_months(sysdate, -1), 'mm') + 15 and sysdate
```

---

After you modified request, then use `case` expression which checks whether today's date is before 16th in month; if so, subtract 1 month - otherwise, don't. In real query, you'd use `sysdate` instead of `today`:

Sample dates:

```
SQL> with temp (today) as
  2    (select date '2023-03-14' from dual union all
  3     select date '2023-03-20' from dual
  4    )
```

Query (once again: you'd use `sysdate` instead of `today`):

```
  5  select today,
  6    trunc(add_months(today,
  7                     case when to_number(to_char(today, 'dd')) < 16 then -1
  8                          else 0
  9                     end), 'mm') + 15
 10      as start_value
 11  from temp;

TODAY      START_VALUE
---------- -----------
2023-03-14 2023-02-16
2023-03-20 2023-03-16

SQL>
```

Comment: This worked great, however I'd like the list to restart once we reach March 16th, so the only value returned is the value on March 16th. So I'm not sure this solution would work between '2023-03-16' and '2023-03-31'. Any solution there?

Comment: You'll have to check today's date, then. Have a look at edited answer.